# I have this issues after the clean and build react native app in xcode

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have these issues after the clean and build react native app in Xcode. anyone knows how to fix these issues. Thanks

[image]

I'm trying to build my react native app on Xcode and these issues are occurred.
my react native version is 0.63.4 and this is react-native info command output -

System:
OS: macOS 13.0.1
CPU: (8) x64 Apple M1
Memory: 27.29 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 16.13.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
npm: 8.1.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/bin/npm
Watchman: 2023.03.20.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /Users/saniranimantha/.rbenv/shims/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 22.1, iOS 16.1, macOS 13.0, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
Xcode: 14.1/14B47b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 19.0.1 - /usr/bin/javac
Python: Not Found
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: ~16.11.0 => 16.11.0
react-native: ~0.63.4 => 0.63.5
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found